# Can I change a disk from drive to mounted?

Tags: mount, windows-server-2008-r2, disk-management

I added a disk to a W2K8R2 machine, and gave it a drive letter: X

I want to change that, and mount it as a folder now.

Is that even possible? How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no server 2008 available to test it, but this is how you do it in windows 7. (Which is mostly the same)

- Go to disk management
- Select the partition you want.
- Right click, change drive letter and paths
- Remove your drive letter, press ok
- Right click, change drive letter and paths (back to the previous screen)
- Add drive letter or path, select *mount in a following empty NTFS folder"
- Press OK, done.

The pictures below show one way to do it. (I am sure there are others, e.g. using the prompt).

[image: Via desktop to computer manage]

[image: From manage to disk management]

[image: Remove drive letter]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if drives can be mounted as folders in windows at all.

I would mount the drive the normal way and create a symbolic link in the place I'd need the folder to be.

```
mklink /d C:\dir\to\link X:\
```

Not sure if this works, as I have no win machine at hand right now.

Comment: as I said this is the way I'd do it, it might be quick and dirty but it would suffice in the use cases I can think of.

Comment: You can mount as folders with the disk management. I just don't know if I can change from already define as drive to mounted folder