# Partition not visible in My Computer

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning

After reinstalling windows 7 on my laptop, the D drive in the previous installation of windows is not visible in My Computer, but I can see it in Disk Management (with no alphabet tag). I can't access my data.

Is there any way to access my data?

[image]

Comment: Assign drive letter so that you can access your old data.

Comment: @vembutech how can I assign drive letter...???

Comment: Diskmanagement, right click, add letter. See [this post](http://superuser.com/questions/482309/can-i-change-a-disk-from-drive-to-mounted) for screenshots.

Answer (score 2):

Partitions or volumes in Windows need to be *mounted* to access them and their files. Mount points can be traditional DOS style drive letters, or even mounted as folders on another drive. There is no requirement to mount, or have a drive letter assigned to a healthy partition. A new installation of windows will often assign drive letters arbitrarily.

The screen-shot of disk manager shows your missing volume to be a healthy NTFS partition, you can mount it as follows:

1. Right click on the partition and choose `Change Driver Letter and Paths`
2. Click `Add`, select a drive letter, and click `OK`

You may first have to modify the existing drive letter assignments to free up the drive letter you want to assign to your partition.

Note if there are programs installed on a volume that you re-mount, or you have programs that refer to files on that volume, you may have to re-install or re-configure any such software.